(Celery + rabbitmq) worker keeps disconnecting
I have a celery worker inside a docker image
and rabbitmq inside a docker image
two separate networks
celery app works normally but when running a long time task it fails
tried time.sleep for 10 minutes, it did not fail
but when tried a function with infinite loop for 10 minutes, it raised an error
on windows it said
raise RecoverableConnectionError('Socket was disconnected')
    amqp.exceptions.RecoverableConnectionError: Socket was disconnected

and on linux it said
Error cleaning up after event loop: RecoverableConnectionError(None, 'Socket was disconnected', None, '')
OSError: Server unexpectedly closed connection

I'm using two docker compose files for each project
docker compose for rabbitmq:
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
    environment:
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "test"
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "test"
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"

for celery:
services:
  celery:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "celery -A celery_project purge -Q test_load_balancer_q -f && python test.py && celery -A celery_project worker -l info -Q test_load_balancer_q --pool solo --logfile=/code/celery.logs"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - .:/code/

this is just to reproduce the issue
the task:
from celery_project import app
import time
import logging


@app.task(queue="test_load_balancer_q", acks_late=True)
def test_task():
    start_time = time.time()
    duration = 600  # 10 minutes in seconds
    
    # Simulating a task by doing continuous work until 10 minutes have passed
    while (time.time() - start_time) < duration:
        # Perform some non-trivial work (e.g., calculations)
        _ = sum(i**2 for i in range(10000))

    logging.info("Task completed after 10 minutes")

in rabbitmq logs I can see
missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s

the error shows after task is done
I had a script before and the error was showing in the middle of the task
either way I think the acks_late causing the task to be called again and again as the worker lost connection and could not acknowledge the task
avoiding task repeat is one thing but how to avoid such an error in the first place?
Edit
I ran the same task without docker (kept rabbitmq in docker)
it worked fine, why is this related to docker?
Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11.3-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc g++

WORKDIR /code/

RUN pip install celery

COPY . .



hi, what's the behaviour if you run both on the same host / network (using docker for both)
